# insert values into table with auto increment primary key? I keep getting errors

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, so I'm getting the error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE links (
        ID smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
        Position smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
        Name text NOT NULL,
        url text NOT NULL,
        IP text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
        ) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

using this command:

```
INSERT INTO links(Position, Name, url, IP) VALUES(0, "Google", "http://www.google.com", "0.0.0.0")
```

The table is only has one row in it, so why the heck isn't the auto increment working? :<

Comment: Try removing the DEFAULT constraint on ID

Comment: Removed, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try the answer below, that should fix it for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually defining the `ID` column as an auto-increment column.  Also, a `DEFAULT` value doesn't make sense for an auto incrementing column either.

Your id column should be:

```
ID smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Whoops. Well that worked. I'll add it as the answer when I can. :> Thank you ^_^